# Hibernate - Table and Sequence in different schema

Tags: hibernate

I have table is *Schema A* and the sequence in *Schema B*. I'm using user C which has permissions on both Table and Schema. When I'm running the `Select B.sequence.nextval` from dual I get the value. But when I'm using `objSession.saveOrUpdate(EntityObject);` It says cannot insert *NULL* into field annotated with sequence. Below is code snippet.

**ENITY CLASS:**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name="BB_BPE.DRUGLISTINPUTFILE") 
public class DrugListInputFileEntity implements Serializable {  

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id     
    @SequenceGenerator(name="DL_DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ROW_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="BB_BPXAPP.ROW_ID_SEQ", allocationSize=1)     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DL_DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ROW_ID_GENERATOR")    
    @Column(name="BPX_ROW_ID")  
    private long bpxRowId;

    ...

}
```

ERROR:

> Hibernate: select BB_BPXAPP.ROW_ID_SEQ.nextval from dual Hibernate:
>   insert into BB_BPE.DRUGLISTINPUTFILE (BC_STATUS, BPX_ACTION_FLAG,
>   BPX_CREATED_DATE, BPX_CREATED_USER, BPX_DUP_IND, BPX_HASH, BPX_ID,
>   BPX_MODIFIED_DATE, BPX_MODIFIED_USER, BPX_ORIGINAL_ROW_ID, BPX_SET_ID,
>   BPX_SOURCE, BPX_STATUS, BPX_VERSION, BPX_XML_FILE_ID,
>   DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ID, filedatetime, filesource, X_CLIENTDRUGLIST,
>   xsdversion, BPX_ROW_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:144 - SQL Error:
>   1400, SQLState: 23000 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - ORA-01400: cannot
>   insert NULL into ("BB_BPE"."DRUGLISTINPUTFILE"."BPX_XML_FILE_ID")

Comment: Your sequence generator is not working probably. Please post its code.

Comment: I ran select B.sequence.nextval from Dual using SqlQuery and it was able to fetch value. I think there there is something wrong using 2 different schema in Entity class, does Hibernate understand that?

Answer (score 0):

try with `schema ="BB_BPXAPP"`

```
    @Id     
    @SequenceGenerator(name="DL_DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ROW_ID_GENERATOR", 
                       schema ="BB_BPXAPP"
                       sequenceName="ROW_ID_SEQ", 
                       allocationSize=1)     
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, g 
                      enerator="DL_DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ROW_ID_GENERATOR")    
    @Column(name="BPX_ROW_ID")  
    private long bpxRowId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Appending schema name to the sequence name worked for me

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="DL_DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ROW_ID_GENERATOR",schema ="BB_BPXAPP",sequenceName="BB_BPXAPP.ROW_ID_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="DL_DRUGLISTINPUTFILE_ROW_ID_GENERATOR")
```